# (Cyclic) edge-connectivity for lifts of voltage graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Can someone point me in the direction of what's known about edge connectivity (or, ideally, cyclic edge connectivity) of graphs which are lifts of voltage graphs? It seems like someone should have studied this, but so far I've not come up with much. Ideally, what I'm hoping for is that there's some sort of results that says 'if you know blah about the structure of the voltage graph, then you can say blah blah about the structure of the lift graph'.